# Visual Studio 2010 - new line on paste

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have just came accross this "feature" and it starts to annoy me a lot. The thing is that when I paste a line of code it gets pasted into a new line regardles where i click or place the caret. Anyone knows why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of a feature Visual Studio 2010 has, which eases line duplication. You can press Ctrl+C when the caret is on the line you want to copy (without selecting anything) and you can paste anything in the current line without selecting anything either. The other lines are pushed down.

Comment: and how can I turn this feature off. As you described it this is a really nice feature but I got used to the "old" way :)

Comment: This feature was present in VS2008 also. What 'old way' are you used to?